# Image error, not loading for S3 image retrieval

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, temporary-files

I have written code on my backend (hosted on Elastic Beanstalk) to retrieve a file from an S3 bucket and save it back to the bucket under a different name. I am using boto3 and have created an s3 client called 's3'.

`bucketname` is the name of the bucket, `keyname` is name of the key. I am also using the `tempfile` module

```
tmp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
with open(tmp.name, 'wb') as f:
    s3.download_fileobj(bucketname, keyname, f)    
s3.upload_file(tmp, bucketname, 'fake.jpg')
```

I was wondering if my understanding was off (still debugging why there is an error) - I created a `tempfile` and opened and saved within it the contents of the object with the `keyname` and `bucketname`. Then I uploaded that temp file to the bucket under a different name. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Getting any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `upload_file()` command is expecting a filename (as a `string`) in the first parameter, *not* a `file` object.

Instead, you should use `upload_fileobj()`.

However, I would recommend something different...

If you simply wish to **make a copy of an object**, you can use [`copy_object`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.copy_object):

```py
response = client.copy_object(
    Bucket='destinationbucket',
    CopySource='/sourcebucket/HappyFace.jpg',
    Key='HappyFaceCopy.jpg',
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much John! Take care!